# How to call javascript function reset() from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to call JavaScript `reset()` function by using button `onclick` method. The code is embedded in PHP as follows :

```
<?php    
echo "<form>";
echo "<input type='text' name='keyword'>";
echo "<input type='button' value='Clear' onclick='<script>reset();</script>'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

The clear button is not working.

Comment: Why not to use `<input type="reset" />`?

Comment: do you mean `<input  type="reset">`? :)

Comment: But I think he is trying to call a function named reset();

Comment: I know, so I ask here. Value button is Clear and onclick call `reset`. Maybe OP is trying to do the same thing but the worst way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to replace input button line with following:

```
echo "<input type='button' value='Clear' onclick='javascript:reset()'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php    
  echo "<form>";
  echo "<input type='text' name='keyword'>";
  echo "<input type='button' value='Clear' onclick='reset()'";
  echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work - But i would try to get away from putting event handlers inline like this. Perhaps you could use jquery instead.

Below however is a 'Vanilla javascript" solution as you requested...

```
<?php 
echo "
    <form>
    <input type='text' name='keyword'>
    <input type='button' value='Clear' onclick='this.parentNode.reset()' >
    </form>
 ";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want :

```
 <?php    
   echo "<form>";
   echo "<input type='text' name='keyword'>";
   echo " <input type='button' value='Clear' onclick='reset();'>";
   echo "</form>";
?>
```

Another way to show HTML code in PHP :

Instead of using `echo` you can just put any HTML or Javascript code in side this `?> HTML | JAVASCRIPT CODE <?PHP`

If you want to put PHP code inside that HTML code you can do the normal procedure which is this :

Example :

```
<?php   
     // Here it can be any PHP code 
    ?>
     <form>
     <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'phpinsidehtml';?>"> //This is an example 
     <input type='text' name='keyword'>
     <input type='button' value='Clear' onclick='reset();'>
     </form>
     <?php
    ?>
```

Comment: I am echoing the form using PHP. So I need to call the javascript reset function for onclick

Comment: I have been coding for good amount of time to be honest , and cant find a different in both ways , but if you tried the code its actually working .